# Nested div will not grow using flexbox

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to build a form where a multiple-choice `<select>` element grows or shrinks based on the space made available to it.

However, the `div.field` it is nested inside refuses to change size, despite being set to `flex 1 1 auto;` ([Code pad here](https://jsfiddle.net/y510vpd8/1/))

The other flexbox elements on the page do the right thing. `fieldset.members` has no trouble expanding and collapsing.

If I set `.field` to have a fixed height, say 300px, the `select` will expand to fill it without a problem.

If I set `.field` to `height: 100%` (which as far as I can tell should not be necessary to get flexbox to do the right thing), Firefox shows the correct result, but Chrome has the `select` overflowing its bounds and taking up the whole page.

I thought that maybe it was something funny to do with it containing a `select` element, so I made a [test code pad with just a div](https://jsfiddle.net/a2zsrmqg/1/) instead of a `select`. It still fails to expand in the same fashion as the `select` element.

I have been hitting my head against this problem for two full days. Google has not gotten me anywhere. Does anyone here know why this problem is appearing and how to fix it?

Here's an example not on a codepad:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.group-creator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.group-creator fieldset {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.group-creator fieldset.members {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: snow;
}
.members legend {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.members .field {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
}
.members .field .inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<form class="group-creator">
  <fieldset class="members">
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="inner">
        asdf
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Create Conversation</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: There's no `<select>` element in your mcve.

Comment: Correct. I inlined the even-simpler proof of concept code, with a `div` (.inner) instead of a `select`, in case the `select` element was the cause of unexpected behavior.

Comment: The problem is due to the `fieldset`, not the `select`.